# Changing encryption settings for Microsoft Office 2010/2013

Tags: microsoft-office, encryption, aes

> **Although there are Office 2013 settings to change how encryption is performed**, when you encrypt Open XML Format files (.docx, .xslx, .pptx, and so on) the default values — AES (Advanced Encryption Standard), 128-bit key length, SHA1, and CBC (cipher block chaining) — provide strong encryption and should be fine for most organizations.

Quoted from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179125.aspx . I can't figure out where is the setting to change how encryption is performed.

Is there any possible to change the encryption algorithm being used instead of the default AES-128 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I tell you how, let me first repeat the advice from... everywhere... and say *don't*.  Unless you have a really, really good reason, don't change the encryption settings from the default, because it's going to cause you a lot of headaches, and probably not provide much benefit.

Having said that, the encryption behavior in Office is controlled through the registry, so that's where you need to go.

1. [You can use the Office Customization Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35554).

   - [The Office Customization Tool (OCT) reference for Office 2013 is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

     - `The OCT is available only with volume licensed versions of Windows Installer-based Office 2013, Office 2010, and the 2007 Office system.`
     - The document you quoted in your question is referencing options in the OCT, so that's probably why you can't find them - they're not configured through any particular Office application.
2. [Download and use the Office 2013 Administrative Template files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35554).

   - [The documentation for your available settings and what they do is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723552%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
3. You can edit the registry.

   - The registry key that controls the Office encryption settings is: `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Security`

     - It's a `REG_SZ` data type, and the value should be something like: `Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider,AES 128,128`

       - The formatting of the key value is comma separated values for the cryptographic provider, the encryption algorithm and key length.
     - Changes to this key only take effect if you don't have crypto compatibility mode set (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\\Security\Crypto\CompatMode` - a value of `1` means compatibility mode is on, a value of `0` means it's off).

Answer (score -2):

In Access 2013

Under File - Options - Client Settings (scroll to the bottom)...

Encryption Method = Use legacy

Comment: This is only a partial answer. OP asked for office (winword.exe, excel.exe, optionally access (only in some versions of office), optionally outlook (also only in some versions of ms office), ...

Comment: We accept partial answers on Super User, so long as they identify themselves as such, as this poster has done.